# .net authentication with sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, authentication

My boss, a dba, is telling me there is a way to authenticate a .net web site using sql server 2005 and later.  Not forms authentication, not nt authentication, not passing a sql server login in a connection string, etc., but using sql server.  Apparently you can let it handle everything.  I have not been able to find anything on this.  Any ideas?

Comment: Get the details from your boss. I have not heard of any such magical authentication (that is, not using a SQL Login or Windows Authentication).

Comment: authenticate a website to what? allow the site's code to access sql server?

Comment: @Oded were I you I would say the same.  But, alas, I am not you.

Comment: You can't ask your boss to teach you and enlighten you?

Comment: It is unfortunate that oded, mark_s and casperOne feel like they are some kind of super mega-gods and close questions that they cannot answer.  Icarus on the other hand, did give me the information I needed and from that I solved the problem.  Well, oded, if I could, I would close you as not being constructive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server Authentication is really either rolling out Forms authentication yourself or use the out-of-the-box [SqlMembershipProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider?view=netframework-4.8). The MSDN documentation has a very comprehensive example there.

Comment: That looks like it. Thanks. a video: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-set-up-the-sql-membership-provider  msdn how to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx